What should I do if someone keeps assaulting me and slandering my reputation?
Hello hope you are all well. So I live in adult foster care and I've been here 3 years 2 okay and one terrible. A few months back the staff started screaming at me and calling me names then it escalated into physical violence. Also I have heard with my own ears the staff sit there and speculate or talk bad about the clients. Should I report this behavior to protect myself?

If someone is assaulting you and slandering your reputation, it's crucial to take immediate action.
These are serious offenses that can have significant consequences.
Here are some steps you can consider:
Keep a detailed record of the incidents, including:
Dates, times, and locations.
Descriptions of the assaults and slanderous statements.
Names of witnesses.
Any evidence, such as photos, videos, or text messages.
File a police report for both the assault and slander. Provide as much detail as possible about the incidents.
If the person continues to harass or threaten you, consider applying for a restraining order to protect yourself.
A lawyer can advise you on your legal options and help you navigate the legal process.
Talking to others who have experienced similar situations can provide emotional support and practical advice.

Ofcourse you should seek help from someone trustworthy and someone in power to do so. Not standing up against injustice is injustice itself.A hadith states that Allah has made oppression unlawful for both himself and his servants, and that people should not commit oppression against each other.
